# How to get the username of a person you pinged in a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on a code in which sends a hug embed in discord.js

this is my code:
(the prefix is set to -->  `

```
  if (message.content === prefix + "hug") {
      return
  }
});




client.on ("message", message => {
  const user = message.author.username;
  const bid = (message.content.replace(prefix + "hug ",''));
  const rex = bid.replace("@!", "");
  const rl = rex.replace("<", "");
  const rr = rl.replace(">", "");

  const idtoname = client.users.cache.get(rr);

  

  

  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content === prefix + "hug") return;

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "hug")) {
  
      const hugembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(user + " hugs " + idtoname.username)
      .setColor(0xbc13fe)
      .setImage("https://www.dropbox.com/s/450lk7apiuf0uk0/huggoooo.gif?dl=1");
      message.channel.send(hugembed);
  
      
  }
});
```

The code is basically sends an embed with a hug gif, and the title is (message.author.username) " hugs " (the person i pinged)

The problem is, i am using the sender's message, and replacing everything else except the id, and converting the id into username

but the problem arises when someone message **prefix + hug (no ping, just text)**, or **prefix + hug (more than 1 pings)**, the bot crashes in both the scenarios.

**Is there any way i can store the username of the person i pinged using `hug command in a variable, and use that instead of replacing the message itself?**

Answer (score 0):

Define the mention, no need to check message content, there's already `message.mentions` (mentions = pings)

```
const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Check for text only, no mentions

```
if (!mentionedUser) {
   return message.channel.send('Please mention a user')
}
```

Use the data

```
const hugembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${user} hugs ${mentionedUser.username}`)
      .setColor(0xbc13fe)
      .setImage("https://www.dropbox.com/s/450lk7apiuf0uk0/huggoooo.gif?dl=1");
      message.channel.send(hugembed);
```

Comment: this solved the problem of bot crashing when 2 users pinged, but gives the same trouble when text is written instead of mention

Comment: I have edited my answer to include text handling

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.on ("message", message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  const user = message.author.username;

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "hug")) {
    const mentioneduser = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!mentionuser) return message.channel.send(`You need to mention a user to give a hug to!`)
  
      const hugembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${user} hugs ${mentioneduser.user.username}`)
      .setColor(0xbc13fe)
      .setImage("https://www.dropbox.com/s/450lk7apiuf0uk0/huggoooo.gif?dl=1");
      message.channel.send(hugembed);  
  }
});
```

Comment: If you would also like to show that user's nickname on the server you can do `${mentioneduser.displayName}`.